# Highcharts Stock - rangeSelector results are not consistent - 3M showing 5 months data

Tags: highcharts

only difference between these two examples are data :

1. http://jsfiddle.net/cyjs868p/3/ - Working fine (3M shows 4 months data. Apr - Jul which is normal)

   Apr 14th -[1460592000000, 98.53]

[image: working]

2.http://jsfiddle.net/cyjs868p/2/ - Not working properly (Issue 3M shows 5 months data. Mar - Jul)

```
Apr 25th -[1461542400000, 98.53]
```

[image: not working]

Comment: It looks like problem you have may be connected with minRange parameter. Try to set it to small value (for example 1). Here you can find information about this parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minRange solved it. Thanks Grzegorz

```
xAxis: {
    minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600000
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyjs868p/5/